# Javascript to pull multiple Google Spreadsheets data for drawing charts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-visualization

I am trying to use Google App Script/Javascript to make a dashboard that is based on data pulled from several sheets in a Google Spreadsheet file. Below is the functional codes to start with, which can successfully draw a chart of August data. What I want is to append July data (Sheet 2) to the chart as a second series. Is it possible?

If I could figure out how to store and access the data table of each month, I guess I should be able use the `.join()` method to merge those tables. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=en#join

Appreciate it in advance for any help!

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Test
    </title>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['table', 'controls', 'corechart']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

      function initialize() {

              var urlMonth = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_mSbT87MVWOiX2cfKX_x3dgTnToY5ulCWeGGCVn13iQ/gviz/tq?sheet=Sheet1&tq='   
              
              var queryStringMonthly = encodeURIComponent("SELECT B, sum(C), sum(D), sum(E), sum(F), sum(G), sum(H) GROUP BY B LABEL B 'Issue' ");

              var queryMonthCurrent = new google.visualization.Query(urlMonth+ queryStringMonthly);
               queryMonthCurrent.send(megaData); 

      }

     function megaData(monthData) {
        var monthData_table = monthData.getDataTable(firstRowIsHeader = true);

        var monthData_tablePivot = new google.visualization.DataTable();
         monthData_tablePivot.addColumn('string', 'Rep');
         monthData_tablePivot.addColumn('number', 'August');
         monthData_tablePivot.addColumn({type: 'string', label: 'Issue', role: 'annotation'}); 

        var  newRows = []; //

         //iterate through each row
         for (i = 0; i < monthData_table.getNumberOfRows(); i ++) {
          var issue = monthData_table.getValue(i, 0);
          //iterate through each column
          for (j = 1; j < monthData_table.getNumberOfColumns(); j ++ ){
            var newRow = []; // use an array to park [RepName1, tickets#, Issue1]
            rep = monthData_table.getColumnLabel(j);
            newRow.push(rep);
            newRow.push(monthData_table.getValue(i, j));
            newRow.push(issue);
            newRows.push(newRow); //push each newRow to newRows
          }
         }

        monthData_tablePivot.addRows( newRows);

        // Create a dashboard.
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard_div4'));

       // Create filter
        var issueFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
          'containerId': 'filter_div4',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Issue', 
            'ui': {
            'allowMultiple': false,
            'allowNone': false, 
            }
          },
          //Set default filter value
          'state': {'selectedValues': [monthData_table.getValue(0 , 1)]} 
        }
        );

        
        //create chart
        var yearChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
          'containerId': 'current_year',
          'options': {
              'legend': {'position': 'right'},
              //Set the fontsize of labels so they don't show up crazily
              'annotations': {'textStyle': {'opacity': 0},
                             //use 'line' style so to remove the line pointer
                             'style': 'point',
                             'stemLength': 0
                            },
          }
        });

        // bind charts and controls to dashboard 
        dashboard.bind(issueFilter, yearChart);
        // Draw the dashboard.
        dashboard.draw(monthData_tablePivot);         
      }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the dashboard-->
    <div id="dashboard_div4">
      <div id="filter_div4"> </div>
      <div id="current_year" style="align: right; width:1100px; height: 300px;">
      </div>
    </div>    

</html>
```

Comment: I think it is possible, check the documentation https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#creating-material-column-charts and the example related to that. Basically you would need 3 columns as input data. as far as I know when querying the sheets it takes the info from the first one. you could probably manage the information from each month in other sheets and in the first one you can copy the information you will need.

Comment: Hi, @Gerado. Thanks for the comment. My challenge is that I don't know how to return "the info from the first one" because the data table `monthData_tablePivot` is wrapped in the function `megaData(monthData)`.

Comment: in the function "initialize" is where you are calling the google.visualization.Query with your spreadsheet as parameter. that function will retrieve the information from the first sheet in the Spreadsheet. With the select statement you are describing how you want the info organized, what i mentioned is that you could also have the info of July in that sheet and put that info in other column of "monthData_table"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that can solve my problem. If anyone has better solution, I would appreciate it if you can share it here. Basically you can use `finished();` at the end of `megaData(monthData)` function to circumvent the asynchronous javascript. So the structure will look something like below:

```
  function initialize() {

    var urlMonth = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dTeqpX1If74h5_I3POrYkoktSm7FxV47iSUHshhlmI4/gviz/tq?sheet=Sheet1&tq='
    var queryStringMonthly = encodeURIComponent("SELECT B, sum(C), sum(D), sum(E), sum(F), sum(G), sum(H) GROUP BY B LABEL B 'Issue' ");
    var queryMonthCurrent = new google.visualization.Query(urlMonth+ queryStringMonthly);
     queryMonthCurrent.send(megaData);

    var urlOneMonthPrior = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dTeqpX1If74h5_I3POrYkoktSm7FxV47iSUHshhlmI4/gviz/tq?sheet=Sheet2&tq=' 
    var queryStringOneMonthPrior = encodeURIComponent("SELECT B, sum(C), sum(D), sum(E) GROUP BY B LABEL B 'Issue' ");  
    var queryMonthOnePior = new google.visualization.Query(urlMonth+ queryStringOneMonthPrior);
     queryMonthOnePior.send(megaData);

  }

  function megaData(monthData) {
    //...
    //use codes from the question post
    finished();
  }

  function finished() {
    if (dataTables.length != 2) {
    //do nothing if data tables are not fully ready
        return;
    }
    //blahblah do something with all the data tables
   }
```